# Performance Influence, if I write assert(!MyClass.desiredAssertionsStatus || ...)?

Tags: java, performance, assert

I like to use assert statements as long as I can properly deactivate them.

I heard that if wrapping asserts in an if statement, the compiler basically removes them, so they do not have an influence.

```
if (MyClass.class.desiredAssertionStatus(){assert(xyz==true)}
```

Intellij however, allways suggests to "simplify" my statements as follows:

```
assert(!MyClass.class.desiredAssertionStatus() || xyz==true);
```

I would like to know, whether the intellij recommendation can actually have a performance influence, i.e. whether the compiler does not recognize anymore to remove them?

Thanks

Comment: What is the signature of that `desiredAssertionStatus()` method? Is it final static? If not, most likely, no compiler will optimize it "out".

Comment: How could the compiler remove them? It would mean that if you enabled assertions, you wouldn't have any assertions left in the class. Unless you're talking about JIT? You're also wasting your time with micro-optimizing insignificant details like this.

Comment: @GhostCat It's a method of `Class`, not `final`, but `Class` is `final`. It's not `static`. I guess, there's some special handling for this method as disabled asserts are believed to be free.

Answer (score 0):

Asserts are enabled and disabled on the JVM level using startup flags.  When disabled they are basically skipped by the JVM and does not have a performance impact.

Therefore you do not need the if-statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement

```
if (MyClass.class.desiredAssertionStatus(){assert(xyz==true)}
```

looks pretty convoluted and the intellij recommendation misses that what you most probably should write is just

```
assert xyz;
```

Note that this is equivalent to

```
if (CurrentClass.class.desiredAssertionStatus()) {
    if (!xyz) throw new AssertionError(...);
}
```

(*unless you change the assertion status dynamically*, as Holger noted) so you were checking the assertion status twice. This is fully redundant when `MyClass` is the current class and probably nonsensical otherwise.

Comment: Not exactly equivalent. Classes containing `assert` statements copy the value of `desiredAssertionStatus()` into a synthetic `private static final` field during the class initialization and the `assert xyz;` is compiled to the equivalent of `if(MY_ASSERTION_STATUS && !xyz) throw new AssertionError();`. This implies that it is trivial to the JIT to optimize this, however, it also implies that classes do not react on changes of the desired assertion status after their initialization.